# Need proper syntax for pseudocode

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, pseudocode

I have a SQL Server query that looks something like this in pseudocode

```
    SELECT  item_id, 
    item_desc, 
    ship2_name, 
    serial_number,
    invoice_no,
            (CASE WHEN invoice_no <> 'null' THEN 1 END)AS mult_inv, 
            quantity_shipped,
        (CASE WHEN (mult_inv > 1) THEN SUM(quantity_shipped))AS ship_total
    FROM table
```

essentially when an invoice number occurs more than 1 time I need to add the values of the quantity shipped and store them in a new column.

Comment: Sample data and desired results woudl really hep.

Comment: And what did you try on your own? Do you expect us to do your homework?

Comment: This helped me a bunch to get the most from this site.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like your psuedocode is in proper psuedocode syntax. Maybe look up `how to conditionally store data from one table in another table with SQL` or something?

Comment: I updated my code to try to be more specific, I don't know if that helps or if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds like a window function.  This would seem to do what you describe:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column5)
             THEN SUM(column5) OVER ()
        END) as column6
FROM table1;
```

I'm not 100% sure that this is what you really want though.

Comment: Hell of a guess Gordon!

Comment: I don't need to store the sum in column 6 but I need the sum of the values in column six when column 5 occurs more than one time, and I need those new values in a new column to display, I'm sorry I'm not very proficient in SQL and this is my second time using this site so I don't know if I'm giving the right type of information.